# How to remove files which do not end with ".c"?

Tags: bash, wildcards, rm

I have a directory which contains all the C programs. I have also compiled them at the creation time so as to check my code. There are a lot of programs nearly 100 of them. So I want a BASH script that would check whether the file ends with ".c". If it does then it does not do anything, which if it doesn't then it would remove them. Suppose one of my file name is "Hello.c" then I have named its binary during compile time as "Hello". So can anyone make this script for me?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `-delete` flag of `find` (first test with `-ls`)

```
find -not -name "*.c" -delete
```

If you do not want to use `find`, but only files in the current directory, you could do

```
rm !(*.c)
```

Make sure in `bash` that with `shopt -s extglob` the correct globbing is set. Additionally, if you have globstar set (`shopt -s globstar`), you can act recursively (for `bash` versions above 4):

```
rm **/!(*.c)
```

Comment: Can also add `-maxdepth 1` to the find to stop recursion.

Comment: even this works. clean and simple!!

Comment: `-delete` is not portable if that matters, you can use `-exec rm` instead.

Comment: If `rm !(*.c)` generates `event not found` in bash, it needs to be proceeded with `shopt -s extglob`.

Comment: As usual, recommendation to first run *without* `-delete` to make sure you didn't make any potentially disastroud mistake.

Comment: And how to combine it with another extension ?

Comment: If I remember correctly `rm **/!(*.c|*.h)` but I am not too sure

Answer (score 5):

I always prefere `find` in such cases. You have not worry about special filenames and you may handle different filetypes. If you like to delete files only, you should add `-type f` to your options. So my favorite solution is:

```
find -not -name "*.c" -type f -delete
```

But be careful. Testing such commands is always a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

Activate ksh extended [wildcard patterns](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-pattern-matching) with the command `shopt -s extglob` (you can put this in your `~/.bashrc`). Then the pattern `!(*.c)` matches all files in the current directory except the ones that match `*.c`:

```
rm !(*.c)
```

This is pretty dangerous as it deletes `.txt` files, `.h` files, etc. A less drastic command would be

```
rm !(*.*) *.o
```

This still deletes `README`, `Makefile`, etc. You should maybe only delete executable files:

```
find . -type d -prune -o -type f -perm -100 -exec rm {} +
```

Shorter, if your `find` supports it:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -perm -100 -delete
```